# Update the HPA cool down period on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to prevent the Horizontal auto-scaler from scaling down too early.I came across a  doc that mentions we can update `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml` file on master node and edit this flag `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-stabilization`.
Is it possible for GKE in Google Cloud ?
As far I know we cannot access the master node on GKE.

Comment: Have you looked into policies and behavior definition? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in GKE you can change the flag on the master node as it's a google managed service.

You can use other options like custom metrics or custom HPA solutions.

For implementing the **custom HPA** solution instead of **default K8s HPA** you can checkout the : https://github.com/nanit/kubernetes-custom-hpa

you can check the configuration flag `behavior.scaleDownCooldown` which takes the time in **seconds** in which the HPA should wait before scaling down again.

Answer (score 1):

Per the Kubernetes official documentation [1] tuning the global HPA settings exposed as flags for the `kube-controller-manager` component.
The flags for the `kube-controller-manager` are actually read from a configuration tar file when the master is created. The master node is managed by Google and they aren’t configurable by customers, so there’s no way to modify this parameter for now. However, I found this public issue [2].
A feature needs to have a handful of stars and, hopefully, comments from several users about how the feature would be useful, hence, there’s no ETA on implementation. Refer to this document [3].

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-cooldown-delay

[2] https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117897819

[3] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests